# What are some examples of cohomology theories without a corresponding classifying space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, higher-category-theory

The general nonsense of cohomology theories is that each one "should" be presented by a classifying space, so that maps into this space give the cohomology (before passing to connected components). For cohomology with coefficient group $G$, this is the classifying space $\mathbf{B}G$ (**Edit.** The representing object here should be the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum for the group). Cobordism is represented by the universal Thom spectrum of the (stable?) orthogonal group, $MO$. Topological K-theory is represented by a categorification of the integers, generally the smooth stack $\mathbf{Vect}$. However useful this concept is, the $n$Lab consistently says that "most" cohomology theories have a corresponding classifying object. There must be some examples, then, of theories without. What are they, and what prevents them from having classifying spaces?

Comment: Anything that doesn't satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. For example, compactly supported cohomology (not homotopy invariant). Look up Brown representability.

Comment: Can we expect these extraneous cases to be captured instead in mapping spaces into a classifying object in a suitably modified $(\infty ,1)$-topos, or is that unreasonable?

Comment: For cohomology with coefficients an abelian Group G then it is $K(G,n)$, not BG. If G is non abelian i think one has $H^1(-;G)=[-,BG]$ not surefor higher stuff

Comment: @Riccardo Thanks, my bad! I was thinking of G-principle bundles. I suppose thinking of the tower of n-fold deloopings of a group as a spectrum shows that G-principle bundles are something like a cohomology theory as well.